# SSH login with bash

Tags: bash, ssh

Trying to login to ssh with a bash script and I cannot get the following to work:

```
export SSH_FLAGS="-i ~/.ssh/my-keypair"
ssh $SSH_FLAGS $user@$host
```

But this code works perfectly:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my-keypair $user@$host
```

Why do I see this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `~` is not special in quotes. Use `$HOME` instead:

```
export SSH_FLAGS="-i $HOME/.ssh/my-keypair"
ssh $SSH_FLAGS $user@$host
```